# Query com mais de um campo de exibição

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Tenho dúvida em como realizar a query exibindo dois campos, consigo apenas com um.
Tenho a Tabela Clientes (id, nome, data de nascimento) e a tabela Transações (`id_trans`, `id_clien`, `valor_trans`).
Preciso que a query mostre o total gasto por cliente com os campos: `nome_clie`, `id_clie`, `total_trans`).

Quando eu tento adicionar uma segunda coluna para exibir da erro, só funciona com nome e total gasto.

Essa é a minha query que funciona, preciso que ela exiba também o ID do cliente, só aparece o nome.

```
select
  nm_cli,
  sum(vl_trn) as tot_trn
from
  tb_cli left join tb_trn on (tb_cli.id_cli = tb_trn.id_cli)
group by nm_cli;
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá e qual foi a SQL executada?

Comment: Error Code: 1052. Column 'id_cli' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: select nm_cli,
sum(vl_trn) as tot_trn
from tb_cli
 left join tb_trn
    on (tb_cli.id_cli = tb_trn.id_cli)
 group by nm_cli;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `id_cli` existe nas duas tabelas que estás a juntar, por isso o SQL não sabe qual pretendes demonstrar (por isso indica que é "ambíguo"). É necessário indicar de qual tabela pretendes usar.

Tenta isto:

```
select
  Cli.id_cli, -- nota aqui a indicação de qual tabela vem a coluna 
  nm_cli,
  sum(vl_trn) as tot_trn
from tb_cli Cli
left join tb_trn Tra on (Cli.id_cli = Tra.id_cli)
group by Cli.id_cli, nm_cli; -- necessário também agrupar pelo Cli.id_cli
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Muito Obrigado!
Mas fiquei com uma dúvida, eu já não especifiquei de que tabela vem as colunas escrevendo "(tb_cli.id_cli = tb_trn.id_cli)"?
E depois do select tem o FROm que tambem deveria referenciar a tabela certa.
Agradeço novamente.

Comment: Sim, especificaste no `JOIN`. No entanto, no `SELECT` não pode haver ambiguidade e como tal tens mesmo que indicar a que tabela pertence a coluna, caso exista, com o mesmo nome, em mais que uma tabela.

Comment: Perfeito, compreendi. Ultima dúvida, esse trecho "from tb_cli Cli" ta criando um alias para a tb_cli? Porque eu mudei para "tb_cli as Cli" e ainda funciona. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, é exatamente isso. A keyword `AS` é opcional na maioria dos DBMS (incluindo MySQL). Por vezes o seu uso pode tornar a query mais legível, mas é apenas isso.

Answer (score 0):

O que faltou foi o group by do campo que você quer trazer, quando não função agregadoras não precisa, MIN MAX COUNT SUM AVG.

Lembre-se de  tratar o valor nulo da transação, caso o cliente não tenha nenhuma transação vai retornar 0.

```
SELECT c.id_cli,
       c.nm_cli,
       sum(isnull(t.vl_trn, 0))
FROM tb_cli c
LEFT JOIN tb_trn t ON t.id_cli = c.id_cli
GROUP BY c.id_cli
ORDER BY c.id_cli,
         c.nm_cli
```

Outra ressalva é se tiver cliente com o mesmo nome pode retornar o valor inesperado, o mais acertado seria fazer uma subquery para trazer o nome baseado no id do cliente e remover do group by:

```
SELECT sub.id_cliente,
       cli.nome,
       sub.valor
FROM
  (SELECT c.id_cli AS id_cliente,
          sum(isnull(t.vl_trn, 0)) AS valor
   FROM tb_cli c
   LEFT JOIN tb_trn t ON t.id_cli = c.id_cli
   GROUP BY c.id_cli) AS sub
JOIN tb_cli cli ON cli.id_cli = sub.id_cliente
ORDER BY sub.id_cliente,
         cli.nome
```

Comment: Verdade, é algo a se pensar, ainda estou engatinhando no SQL. Agradeço a ajuda!